# Can someone explain the structure of a Pid (Process Identifier) in Erlang?

Tags: erlang, pid

Can someone explain the structure of a Pid in Erlang?

Pids looks like this: `<A.B.C>`, e.g. `<0.30.0>` , but I would like to know what is the meaning of these three "bits": `A`, `B` and `C`.

`A` seems to be always `0` on a local node, but this value changes when the Pid's owner is located on another node.

Is it possible to directly send a message on a remote node using only the Pid? Something like that: `<4568.30.0> ! Message`, without having to explicitly specify the name of the registered process and the node name ( `{proc_name, Node} ! Message`)?

Comment: Ok, my main problem is fixed. I was simply not sending the good pid to the remote side...

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Printed process ids < A.B.C > are composed of [6](http://github.com/mfoemmel/erlang-otp/blob/R13B/erts/emulator/beam/erl_term.h#L502):

- A, the node number (0 is the local
  node, an arbitrary number for a remote node)
- B, the first 15 bits of the process number (an index into the process table) [7](http://github.com/mfoemmel/erlang-otp/blob/R13B/erts/emulator/beam/erl_term.h#L534)
- C, bits 16-18 of the process number (the same process number as B) [7](http://github.com/mfoemmel/erlang-otp/blob/R13B/erts/emulator/beam/erl_term.h#L534)

Internally, the process number is 28 bits wide on the 32 bit emulator. The odd definition of B and C comes from R9B and earlier versions of Erlang in which B was a 15bit process ID and C was a wrap counter incremented when the max process ID was reached and lower IDs were reused.

In the erlang distribution PIDs are a little larger as they include the node atom as well as the other information. ([Distributed PID format](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/erl_ext_dist.html#8.8))

When an internal PID is sent from one node to the other, it's automatically converted to the external/distributed PID form, so what might be `<0.10.0>` (`inet_db`) on one node might end up as `<2265.10.0>` when sent to another node. You can just send to these PIDs as normal.

```
% get the PID of the user server on OtherNode
RemoteUser = rpc:call(OtherNode, erlang,whereis,[user]), 

true = is_pid(RemoteUser),

% send message to remote PID
RemoteUser ! ignore_this, 

% print "Hello from <nodename>\n" on the remote node's console.
io:format(RemoteUser, "Hello from ~p~n", [node()]).
```

For more information see: [Internal PID structure](http://github.com/mfoemmel/erlang-otp/tree/5b6dd0e84cf0f1dc19ddd05f86cf04b2695d8a9e/erts/emulator/beam/erl_term.h#L498),
[Node creation information](http://github.com/mfoemmel/erlang-otp/tree/5b6dd0e84cf0f1dc19ddd05f86cf04b2695d8a9e/erts/emulator/beam/erl_node_container_utils.h#L24),
[Node creation counter interaction with EPMD](http://erlang.2086793.n4.nabble.com/PID-recycling-td2108252.html#a2108255)

Comment: It turns out I was wrong about the creation counter after looking at the source closely. Thanks to Wallentin for prompting me to do that.

I'm now sure about the bit sizes of B and C, but didn't completely follow the _GET_BITS macro in the erts source, so not sure if I'm right about top vs. bottom bits.

Answer (score 14):

If I remember this correctly the format is `<nodeid,serial,creation>`. 
0 is current node much like a computer always has the hostname "localhost" to refer to itself. This is by old memory so it might not be 100% correct tough.

But yes. You could build the pid with `list_to_pid/1` for example.

```
PidString = "<0.39.0>",
list_to_pid(PidString) ! message.
```

Of course. You just use whatever method you need to use to build your PidString. Probably write a function that generates it and use that instead of PidString like such:

```
list_to_pid( make_pid_from_term({proc_name, Node}) ) ! message
```

Comment: Did you have seen this big red warning? [list_to_pid/1](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#list_to_pid-1)

And also you can simply send {proc_name, Node} ! message
or use module global if you want use global names.

Comment: Yeah.. Know about these other methods. And that's what I use.

That just wasn't the question. :)

Comment: pid_to_list/1 takes a pid and returns its string representation.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning list_to_pid - just what I was looking for. Here's a bit more info on it (specifically, that you cannot use it with external pids: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10475321/list-convert-to-pid-function-list-to-pid-1-restriction)

Comment: FYI, this matches: `Pid = pid(0,123,0), Pid = list_to_pid("<0.123.0>").` (tested on 18)

Answer (score 8):

Process id < A.B.C > is composed of:

- A, node id which is not arbitrary but the internal index for that node in dist_entry. (It is actually the atom slot integer for the node name.)
- B, process index which refers to the internal index in the proctab, (0 -> MAXPROCS).
- C, Serial which increases every time MAXPROCS has been reached.

The creation tag of 2 bits is not displayed in the pid but is used internally and increases every time the node restarts.

Answer (score 3):

The PID refers to a process and a node table. So you can only send a message directly to  a PID if it is known in the node from which you do the call.

It is possible that this will work if the node you do the call from already [knows about](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/part_frame.html) the node on which the process is running.

Comment: if i issue "nodes()" on the remote node, my local node appears, but i can't register the "remote pid", because list_to_pid fails : "register(client,list_to_pid("<5058.95.0>"))." returns "bad argument".
Am i missing something ?

Comment: You can only register local pids - to register remote pids you'd need to use the global registration module (or roll your own registration system).

Answer (score 1):

Apart from what others have said, you may find this simple experiment useful to understand what is going on internally:

```
1> node().
nonode@nohost
2> term_to_binary(node()).
<<131,100,0,13,110,111,110,111,100,101,64,110,111,104,111,
  115,116>>
3> self().                
<0.32.0>
4> term_to_binary(self()).
<<131,103,100,0,13,110,111,110,111,100,101,64,110,111,104,
  111,115,116,0,0,0,32,0,0,0,0,0>>
```

So, you can se that the node name is internally stored in the pid. More info in [this section](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/distribunomicon#setting-up-an-erlang-cluster) of Learn You Some Erlang.