# What datatype for storing erlang pids in postgresql database?

Tags: postgresql, erlang

I have a need to store erlang pids in an sql database (postgresql).

I could use a varchar(N) but a pid seems to be structurally a sequence of three integers, so I thought there might be something better.  The erlang application is likely to be distributed, so the node part of the pid will not always be zero.

Is it worth creating a composite type as in:

```
CREATE TYPE pid AS (
    a integer,
    b integer,
    c integer
);
```

Will that create problems trying to identify pids across nodes (e.g. if node writing and node reading the db are not the same)?  Or other problems?

Is this too much fuss and I just just use varchar(N)?  In which case is there a maximum string length?

With thanks and best wishes

Ivan

ps I have read these two questions:

- [Can someone explain the structure of a Pid in Erlang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243363/can-someone-explain-the-structure-of-a-pid-in-erlang)
- [global:whereis_name() returns different Pid from different terminals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355685/globalwhereis-name-returns-different-pid-from-different-terminals)

Comment: I don't see why you would want to store Pids in a database. Can you explain why you need to store an internal process id into a backing store?

Comment: Storing pids in a durable store is silly because pids are invalidated when the VM terminates.

Comment: Have you tried using ets or mnesia instead?

Comment: Thanks all.  I can see now that storing pids is a bad idea.  As Marc Worrell has suggested elsewhere, I'm going to try using gen_tracker (which is based on ets):  https://github.com/erlyvideo/gen_tracker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all. I can see now that storing pids is a bad idea. As Marc Worrell has suggested elsewhere, I'm going to try using gen_tracker (which is based on ets): github.com/erlyvideo/gen_tracker