# Is it possible to "run out" of Erlang process IDs?

Tags: erlang, pid

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243363/can-someone-explain-the-structure-of-a-pid-in-erlang) says that Erlang PIDs are actually 28-bit integers, the first 10 of which are the node number (always 0 for the local node), and the next 18 of which are an index into the global process table.  So, if my understanding is correct, assuming we're only working on a single node, the maximum number of unique PIDs is 2^18, or about 262,000.  Is this then the maximum number of processes that I can spawn on a single Erlang node, over time? If I have a very long-running Erlang node, will the VM immediately crash after I allocate my 2^18+1'th node, or do old, unused PIDs get reused?  If so how is that process implemented at the VM level?

Answer (score 5):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/262179/1366533) to the other question seems to refer to an older version of the Erlang runtime, it changed after R9 (R17 is the latest at the moment). According to [the implementation](https://github.com/mfoemmel/erlang-otp/blob/R13B/erts/emulator/beam/erl_term.h#L503) the process id uses **28 bits** for internal identifiers.

Pids are recycled when the process dies and any monitors has been notified, so 2^28 is the upper limit of the number of simultaneous processes on the node.

The default process limit is 2^18 and can be increased with the `+P` option to `erl`, see the [erl options documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html#max_processes).

Note: the documentation says the upper limit is 2^27 processes, that's not consistent with the code.